# Postgres: sanitize string before searchin for it

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models

I have a website which uses Postgres as a database. I now want users to be able to search the database for strings and am using pg_trgm for that.

I can imagine that it is very dangerous to just search the database for the plain user input, as it could be malicious.

So my question is: what security measures do I have to take in order to search for a string in Postgres, which could potentially contain malicious code? Are there for example certain characters which should be escaped?

Thanks in advance,
Kingrimursel

Comment: pg_trgm defines several operators, and provides index support for built-in operators as well.  Different operator have different special characters.

Comment: @jjanes could you please elaborate? I'm sorry, but I don't understand how this is answering my question.

Comment: It isn't an answer at all, it is a comment, saying your question is unanswerably vague.

Comment: To second @jjanes, you will need to provide more information about how the string is getting from A->B->C,etc. Given that you tagged Django I would look at [Django Security](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection), in particular 'SQL injection protection' where it points out the benefits of using query parameters.